# how to add url from json data in the href tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, anchor

i have a url value from the json response which is like

```
url=response.url.urlname;(//suppose this contains the value like www.google.com)
```

now i want to include it in anchor tag in my javascript code
web is div in html page

```
<div id="web>
$("#web").append('<a href="http://"'+url+'"" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">'+url+'</a>');
```

i am unable to load the page.can anybody help me for this concatenation?

Comment: checking if url is set first (console.log) shows correct url? Scope of url var is ok? in generated code - what do you see as href=""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not used quotes properly.

Try this:

```
$("#web").append("<a href='http://"+url+"' rel='external' data-direction='reverse'>"+url+"</a>");
```

OR this:

```
$('#web').append('<a href="http://'+url+'" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">'+url+'</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as you are using bad quotation

```
var url = "www.google.com"
var link = '<a href="http://"'+url+'"" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">'+url+'</a>'
// returns: "<a href="http://"www.google.com"" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">www.google.com</a>"


var url = "www.google.com"
var link = '<a href="http://'+url+'" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">'+url+'</a>'
// returns: "<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">www.google.com</a>"
```